# Introducing a metric in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $M=\mathbb{R}-\left\{0\right\}$ became connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Of course the set $M=\mathbb{R}-\left\{0\right\}$ is not connected with the induced usual metric of $\mathbb{R}$. So my ask is: there is some metric $d$ we put in $\mathbb{R}$ such that we can take $M$ as a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Take a bijection $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ and consider $d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$. Then $M$ is a connected subset in $(\mathbb R, d)$.

Comment: Not if we want the metric to induce to the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.